# Cloud Run and DB migrations: Initial boot timeout when creating a new revision (to use for db migrations)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm looking to migration Cloud Run and I'm wondering about boot times when creating a new revision. Basically when the cloud run revision boots I want to run DB migrations which as everyone knows might take a while.

I know the Cloud Run waits until the container is ready to start serving traffic, but for how long does it wait for it to become ready?

I've searched the documentation but haven't really find anything.

The database is hosted in CloudSQL

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: You want to perform a DB migration when you deploy the revision only once? Or every time that your container is started?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Only once when you deploy it the first time, to not burden the cold boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want out of the box, you need some engineering. In fact, your container is immutable, that means run it 1 time or 1000 times, the same execution is performed. So, if you set a migration script at startup, this script will be played every time.

You can imagine to store the current schema version in your database. And when a Cloud Run instance start with your container, the startup check the schema version, and if it's not equals, apply the migration script and update the schema version.

But at each instance start, the connexion to the DB + the version check will be performed.

---

Another solution is to define a path to start the migration script `/migration`. Call it just after your deployment to apply the migration. This time, no cold start impact, but a path still accessible even after the migration.

Or you can mix both approach, with a check in database of the schema version + a path to apply the migration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) that is a good point. I will do the second approach: Release the new revision without traffic, then send a request to /migration, then once that is done redirect the traffic